# Disable cut ,copy,paste but enable link and scroll in UITextview

Tags: objective-c

How to disable the `cut`,`copy`,`paste` in UITextview but i want to enable link in uitextview Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `UITextFieldDelegate` protocol where `textField:shouldChangeCharactersInRange:` always returns NO. In this way, you can get events but make the field no editable.